# Shortest Time Remaining Algorithm

Tags: process

When a scheduler algorithm is developed, many alternatives can be preferred. One of these alternatives is **shortest time remaining**.

I wonder what happens if these processes enter into the the system:

```
     Arrival     Burst     
P1     0          3
P2     2          6
P3     4          4
P4     6          5
P5     7          2

0-3 = P1        0-3 = P1
3-4 = P2        3-4 = P2
4-8 = P3        4-8 = P3
8-10 = P5       8-10 = P5
10-15 = P2      10-15 = P4
15-20 = P4      15-20 = P2
```

Which one is correct execution order ? Left or right

Comment: What is the burst? is it the deadline? Also what will be the execution time for each process. Is the system preemptable?

Comment: What I mean with the word **burst** is the total time when the processes is executed on the processor in so that they can be finished.